# How to store files out side the public folder in carrierwave?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Carrierwave by default takes in the url generated by `store_dir` in the uploader and prepends the path to the public folder of the rails application and stores the files.

For example if

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.id}"
end
```

then the file is stored at `public/uploads/:attachment_id`

If one tries to move the stored files out of the public folder still it saves in the public folder. Does anyone have an idea of how to store the files outside the public folder??

Answer (score 41, accepted):

the cleanest way to do this, is by setting the CarrierWave root option

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```

then `store_dir` will be used inside this root.

Answer (score 13):

I realize this isn't really a current question, but I stumbled on it looking for something else. The answer is simply to use Rails.root, eg:

```
  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/private/files/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Comment: Be careful as you'll most likely run into a "Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths" error.

Answer (score 8):

A much more cleaner solution would be to define:

```
def store_dir
  nil
end
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory)

Comment: plus1 this is the "official" way

Comment: I don't think so... setting to nil will merely put them at the root of the public folder

Answer (score 0):

Inside the store dir you can also do something like this:

```
 def store_dir
     "#{Rails.root.join('public', 'system', 'uploads')}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end
```

the solution of changing the config_root didn't work for me.

Comment: this does not answer the question how to store them __outside__ the public fodler, it meerely stores them __deeper__ in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

If someone need that just for RSpec then just do

```
describe SomeClass do
  before do
    CarrierWave.stub(:root).
      and_return(Pathname.new "#{Rails.root}/tmp/fake_public")
  end

  it { ... }
end
```

if you want that for all your tests

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.before :each do
    # ...
    CarrierWave.stub(:root).and_return(Pathname.new "#{Rails.root}/tmp/public")
  end
end
```