# Undefined Method Join-error when running CarrierWave and Sinatra.

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave

I'm trying the *[Gentle Introduction to CarrierWave](https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/a-gentle-introduction-to-carrierwave)*-tutorial by using the web-framework Sinatra. When I run my app it starts just fine and the app asks me to upload a file and it does so without any problems. However, while uploading the file, the app throws me an "undefined method `join' for # String:0x3480d50 "-error.

I've looked around a little bit on the internet and I found this [issue at github](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/951) where they say that the error may be due to incompatibilities between Rack and Sinatra or for having installed duplicate versions of Sinatra.

Does anybody know what's happening?

My uploader_app:

```
require 'carrierwave'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'sequel'
require 'carrierwave/sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table :uploads do 
    String :file    
end

# uploader
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :file
end

# model
class Upload < Sequel::Model
    mount_uploader :file, MyUploader
end

# sinatra app
get '/' do
     @uploads = Upload.all
     erb :index
end

post '/' do
    upload = Upload.new
    upload.file = params[:image]
    upload.save
    redirect to('/')
end

__END__

@@ index
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="image" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>
                <% @uploads.each do |upload| %>
                    <img src="<%= upload.file.url %>" />
                <% end %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you share the stack trace with us?

Comment: @iain Sure [link](https://gist.github.com/ljnissen/6f65363175ceb16cd97d) It actually gives me two errors: One NoMethodError as above and one "TypeError: Can't convert nil into string". Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're not going mad. I just installed it and ran it, got the same error. I'm running Ruby 2.1.2 and I sandboxed the gems using bundler, but still failed. I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring on [this line in the Carrierwave Library](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/url.rb#L23):

```
path = encode_path(file.path.gsub(File.expand_path(root), ''))
```

It fails because `root` is `nil`, so `File.expand_path(root)` raises an error. I don't know why root isn't set, but the following code (that I modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998254/335847)) worked for me:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = settings.root
end
```

I just added it to the code after declaring the Sequel class and before defining the route. Probably best to stick it in a [`configure` block too](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration). Note that `settings.root` in the code above is [Sinatra's root setting](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Available%20Settings).

This doesn't seem to be caused by the current problems between Rack 1.6.0 and Sinatra 1.4.5 as that's what I was running, although I'm on Ruby v2.1.2 as I mentioned in the comments above.

Depending on what you want, Sinatra's `root` might not be the best place to put things, as I ended up with a directory inside the project root called "uploads" which had the files in, but `config.root` obviously needs to be set to *something*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think there is a connection with the Rack 1.6.0 – Sinatra 1.4.5 issue. That problem is in the exception handler, so if you fix the original error (as you do here) the `undefined method join` error won’t appear and obscure the original.

Comment: @matt you're right, I forgot the question originally was about the join error and not the type error (even though it really *should* be that way round:)